How to provide list of integers as input in selenium
I have a python script to check result of students but it is using in range function and I want to use defined integers. Please help me regarding this.
# put rollnumber without zero like
# your number 0477593 then
# put 477593 upto XXXXX.
start_rollNum = 2245000092
end_rollNum = 2249553367

# put range of rollnumber
for i in range(start_rollNum, end_rollNum ):

I am noob so I had not tried anything.
I don't want to use for i in range function. Instead of it, I have list of roll numbers to be inserted to check result with the help of selenium and python, please guide me.

I have list of roll numbers to be inserted to check result  ->   for value in my_list_of_numbers:   Selenium has absolutely nothing to do with iterating a range or a list of numbers.

I don't understand your problem. It seems you have problem with basis knowledge. for i in list_of_data:. And it has nothing to do with selenium

Hi there. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information about asking questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow for common questions about Stack Overflow.

Here's a simple example:
roll_numbers = [2245000092, 2246123456, 2249553367]
for i in roll_numbers:
    print(i)

which outputs
2245000092
2246123456
2249553367

